# CDI lifecycle callback AFTER the class is put into service

Tags: jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, cdi, jta, weld

Is there a CDI callback like `@PostConstruct` but that is instead invoked **after** the class is put into service?

I have a `UserDAO` that injects a `EntityManager` and a EJB `UserBean` that injects the `UserDAO`, which is invoked remotely.

When the `UserBean.save(u)` is invoked, it is executed within the transactional EJB scope. But the `EntityManager` injected into `UserDAO` isn't associated with the transaction by the injection time.

If I declare a init method in the `UserDAO` and annotate with `@PostContruct`, the `TransactionSynchronizationRegistry` isn't the same when the EJB method is invoked due to the `@PostConstruct` nature.

This is all correct, because the `@PostConstruct` callback is defined as "Initializing a managed bean specifies the lifecycle callback method that the CDI framework should call after dependency injection **but before the class is put into service.**"

But, if I use the `TransactionSynchronizationRegistry` inside the method `UserDAO.update(u)`, the transaction is the same as `UserBean`.

So, is there a callback method/annotation that I can use **after** the bean is put "into service"? That way I'd be able to put this method in the `UserDAO`, so I can use the `TransactionSynchronizationRegistry` before any method invocation of `UserDAO`.

**Edit:**
The JTA transaction is created when my `userBean.save(u)` method is invoked. But at `@PostContruct` time of `UserDAO` I'm able to inject a valid instance of `TransactionSynchronizationRegistry`, but it is a different transaction with status `STATUS_NO_TRANSACTION` and another transaction-id (different from transaction from `userBean.save(u)`). But I would like to use some informations about the same transaction that originated from the invocation of the `userDAO.save(u)` method in the `@PostConstruct` method of `UserDAO`.

PS: English is not my main language. I'm sorry if I did not make myself clear enough.

Comment: Just a wild thought - have you considered either interceptor or decorator? You can hook it directly onto the method (or all of them) effectively allowing you to do stuff before calling the method. You could wire the EN the first time it is used then do no-op.

Comment: Does your persistence.xml specify JTA transactions or RESOURCE_LOCAL?

Comment: @Siliarus yes, I wrote with the interceptor before. But I was looking for a less invasive approach. tks.

Comment: @SteveC using with JTA

Comment: The lifecycle of your beans should be irrelevant. You should not be able to invoke any business methods before the entire object graph is "put into service". I would normally expect that the current JTA transaction that is created when your `userBean.save(u)` method is invoked (or perhaps before depending upon where this call originates) will be associated with the current thread and picked up by your entity manager.

Comment: @SteveC The JTA transaction is created when my `userBean.save(u)` method is invoked. But at `@Postcontruct` time of `UserDAO` I'm able to inject a valid instance of `TransactionSynchronizationRegistry`, but at this time the transaction status is `STATUS_NO_TRANSACTION` and with other transaction-id (different from transaction from  `userBean.save(u)`)  . I would like to use some informations about the (real) transaction at the creation of `UserDAO` (when its associated with JTA)

Comment: There is no transaction at creation time. You cannot access the transaction until the business method is invoked.

Comment: @SteveC yes, I realized that :( I'm back to the Interceptor approach. Tks!